# \pause not working after "overprint" environment

Tags: beamer, overlays

In the following example, in the pdf I want to pause at the mentioned place. Any solution will be helpful. Thanks

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]
{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center
{title    in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{1em}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}

% Search online for beamer themes to find your favorite or use 
the     Berkeley theme as in this file.
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]


\usepackage{color} % It may be necessary to set PCTeX or 
   whatever       program you are using to output a .pdf instead of a
    .dvi file in order to see color on your screen.
\usepackage{graphicx} % This package is needed if you wish to 
include  external image files.
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
      \theoremstyle{definition} % See Lesson Three of the 
LaTeX Manual  for more on this kind of "proclamation."
\newtheorem*{dfn}{A Reasonable Definition} 

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Use of \alert{sub-sampling} according to deterministic target poilcy from the given behavioural trajectory, then assume
    sub-sampled data is i.i.d
    \begin{overprint}
     \onslide<1>$\textcolor{red}{A}$
     \onslide<2>$\textcolor{red}{B}$ 
    \end{overprint}
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       % I want to pause here
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \item C
               \end{frame}

                \end{document}
```

Also the following is removing "B" from the slide completely after "C" appears

```
    \begin{itemize}
          \item<1-> Use of \alert{sub-sampling} according to 
          deterministic  target poilcy from the given 
          behavioural trajectory, then assume
        sub-sampled data is i.i.d
        \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<2>$\textcolor{red}{A}$
        \onslide<3>$\textcolor{red}{B}$ 
        \end{overprint}

      \item<4-> C
```

I don't want this. I want first "A" to appear, then replaced by "B" and in the next slide "C" should come while "B" remains.

Answer (score 1):

Do you necessarily need `overprint`? Otherwise check out if the following code gives the desired result.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}
      \begin{itemize}
            \item 0
            \only<1>{\item A}
            \item<2-> B
            \item<3> C
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way keeping the `overprint` (using its optional argument to prevent the following material to be pushed down):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intuition: Continued...}

\begin{itemize}
\item Use of \alert{sub-sampling} according to deterministic target poilcy from the given behavioural trajectory, then assume sub-sampled data is i.i.d
\begin{overprint}[3cm]

\only<1>{$\textcolor{red}{A}$}
\only<2->{$\textcolor{red}{B}$} 
\end{overprint}
\item<+(2)-> C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]